# Mongo Grouping doesn't happen at DB level and doesn't use Mongo Aggregation Framework

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

Mongo Grouping doesn't happen at DB level and doesn't use Mongo Aggregation Framework with the following code. Any idea why? I have to create CommandDocument and RunCommand, then only it uses the aggregation framework.

```
public IEnumerable<IGrouping<TKey, T>> GetItemsByQuery<TKey>(IMongoQuery query, FieldsBuilder fieldsBuilder, Func<T, TKey> groupbyKey)
{ 
    var mongoCursor = collection.FindAs<T>(query);
    mongoCursor.SetFields(fieldsBuilder);
    return mongoCursor.GroupBy(groupbyKey);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) The aggregation framework is only support in unstable releases of MongoDB version 2.1 and higher.  It will be formally supported in server 2.2.  So, unless you are running server 2.1 or greater, you won't get this feature server side.

2) The driver does not yet support the aggregation framework.  You can build the aggregation manually and use db.RunCommand to execute it.

3) You are calling the IEnumerable extension method off of a MongoCursor.  MongoCursor does have any idea of what you are asking it to do and therefore, the grouping will happen clientside.  There is a method on the collection called Group, but you'll need to write some javascript to execute that.

All in all, we don't have a great aggregation story yet.  In server 2.2, that will change, but it isn't here yet.